# Can you see what mobile is currently connected to Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to find a way to see the IMEI code of the current logged in user from their mobile device. I see that Acumatica does create an Instance ID but I also have had no luck in seeing a way to check which one is currently being used.

I have found the following:

```
bool mobile = this.Base.IsMobile;
```

This does show that a mobile device is currently connected. Is there a way to see the current connect device IMEI or has some done something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this. This information is not sent from mobile device to acumatica